# MYSQL average of n prior rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-variables

I apologize if this question has been asked before.  I tried to do searches but may not have been using the same wording as others so my searches came up with nothing.

I have a table of just over 6000 rows and I'm trying to do an average of the prior n number of rows of a particular column. In this case, the closing price of a FOREX currency pair. (I know I could use the PHP::Trader but I don't have access to install it on my server.)

I've tried :

```
SELECT *, (SELECT AVG(close) 
    FROM `2015_EURUSD_60min` 
    WHERE (id > (id - 20) AND id <= id)
) 
FROM `2015_EURUSD_60min`
```

This generated the same number for every row and I'm not sure why. Every value in the `id` column is sequential.  I cleaned up the data to make sure of that.

What did I do wrong in my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Thanks Ghost for cleaning up the formatting.  I'll remember that for any future questions.

Comment: id is always > id-20 and id<=id

Comment: in other words, it just does an avg of close for the whole table

Comment: I'm basically trying to get the average of a group, but doing a GROUP BY FLOOR(id/20) , I want each row to be the reference point, so row 20 would get the prior 20 rows average (rows 1 through 20) and row 21 would get average of rows 2 through 21, and row 22 would show the average for rows 3 through 22, etc.

Comment: So how do i use the current row as a reference point and grab data relative to the current row?

Comment: Short of joining all 19 other rows.

Comment: I can do that for ya. But will wait and let someone else give it a crack

Comment: I can do the join as well, I know that it will not be efficient and there has to be a better way.  I've been trying to figure out using variables as well.  MySQL's way of using variables is a different way of thinking.

Comment: You also need to tell people the structure. And if you have id gaps. So they will know if they have to re-rank

Comment: I already addressed the issue of id gaps in the question itself.

Comment: Do you have a timestamp column which you could use to restrict to records you want to average?  This would be much easier than trying to generate row numbers.

Comment: I do have a unix_stamp column.

Comment: @Drew, I appreciate your help.  If you need a break, go take a break.  We appreciate your help, but don't do it to your detriment.

Comment: How many records are there? I saw your answer below stating it took 17 seconds. That's quite long. Are your tables properly indexed? There is also a way of doing direct indexing. Edit: ok 6000 that's not really a lot. Mysql can handle that.

Comment: For id 23, your query evaluates as `23 BETWEEN 3 AND 23`. For id 24, it evaluates as `24 BETWEEN 4 AND 24`. So that's what you did wrong; you didn't use a join
)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer (although slow performance) to my question:

```
SELECT *, @s:=@s+1 serial_num, 
    (SELECT AVG(close) 
     FROM `2015_EURUSD_60min` 
     WHERE (id > (@s-20) AND id <= @s )) prior_id 
FROM `2015_EURUSD_60min`, (SELECT @s:=0) AS s
```

Comment: It took 17.0824 seconds to execute :( Not horrible.  Most of the time in phpMyAdmin was rendering the text for displaying on the screen.